How to pass radare2 a specific payload, but only after "dc"?
I'm trying to inject a particular byte string to radare input. I'd like to do it after a particular dc command, because after that the program will ask
Hello, what's your name?

Something like dc <<< $(python3 -c 'print("\x4c\x40\x40\x00\x00\x00" + "%3$n" + "%6$n")')
I tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59637217/23752619
but does not work:
{ echo -ne '#!/usr/bin/rarun2\nprogram=./formattedctf\ninput='; python3 -c 'print("\x4c\x40\x40\x00\x00\x00" + "%3$n" + "%6$n")'; } > profile.rr2;
$ r2 -d formattedctf -e dbg.profile=profile.rr2
[0x7b99684f2540]> dc
Hello, what's your name?
didntputit
didntputit
That is a nice name!!
(1027327) Process exited with status=0x0
I also tried this: https://github.com/radareorg/radare2/issues/6614
and does not work either:
$ r2 -X "stdin='$(python3 -c 'print("\x4c\x40\x40\x00\x00\x00" + "%3$n" + "%6$n")')'" -d ./formattedctf 
bash: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
[0x004010b0]> dc
Cannot continue, run ood?
[0x00000000]> ood
File dbg:///home/allexj/Downloads/formatted reopened in read-write mode
[0x7af6989fb540]> dc
Hello, what's your name?
didntputit
didntputit
That is a nice name!!
(1027193) Process exited with status=0x0
